# How to import PSD layers into After Effects and maintain their original positions?

Tags: after-effects

When importing a .PSD file into After Effects, I am able to easily maintain my separate layers with their original size, but is it possible to also retain the position of each layer?

Right now, After Effects automatically centers each layer, but I need it to keep it's original position from the PSD file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a photoshop file with four layers - a background, a shape, and two text layers "left" and "right":

[image]

I save as PSD, and import them into After Effects using the "Composition -Retain Layer Sizes" option:

[image]

[image]

Here they are correctly imported into AE with the same positions:

[image]

Comment: Ah. Turns out I was just dragging the individual layers into my comp instead of opening the comp that AE created when I imported the PSD. Thank you.